# The way to store association array into MySQL and retrieve it back in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

E.g:

PHP code:**strong text**

```
// $files would be stored into mysql db and will retrieve as original
$files = array('1' => '1,2,4,5', '5' => '4,5,7,23,56','8' => '45,23,56,67');
```

And the **database table** `file's allFile[char]`

```
'1' => '1,2,4,5', '5' => '4,5,7,23,56','8' => '45,23,56,67'
```

I thought I must convert the array data into string and then store into database,but `implode` only got the `array value` without `key`.So, should I use the `foreach loop` to get the `key/value` into string?

```
foreach ($files as $key => $value){
  $str .= $key.'=>'.$value.','; // remove the last comma of the $str
}
```

and when I retrieve `$str` form database, I get:

```
$files = array($str);
```

So, am I do the right way ?!

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Wouldn't things feel a bit more accessible if you translated the structure of the array into a table and inserted the elements as rows? The database might feel overqualified if you just ask him to hang your text blobs on a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

json_encode/json_decode are a popular choice here, as it means the database content is still readable without PHP. In my quick tests, storing as JSON is also more efficient.

Comment: More importantly, you can use `json_encode` to store wide characters, which PHP's (un)serialize chokes on.

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = serialize($array);
$array = unserialize($string);
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.serialize.php

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.unserialize.php